# What is Grothendieck and Hartshorne's local duality?

Tags: ac.commutative-algebra

I am looking for a simple and brief answer to the following question:
What is Grothendieck and Hartshorne's local duality and what is its relationship with dualizing modules?
How do (semi-)dualizing modules is employed to study local cohomolgy?